# Is it possible to use group multicast (IGMP) over the internet?

Tags: multicast, igmp

I am looking at building an application that broadcasts audio using my own proprietary protocol.  Under the covers I'd prefer to use IGMP or something where 1000 clients don't use 1000 times the networking resources.

Does anybody know if it is possible to use IGMP over arbitrary internet connections?  If I have a server on EC2 or some common host will it be able to get data via multicast to arbitrary clients worldwide in the same way I could host HTTP to arbitrary people?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Multicast is not enabled on the Internet. So if you directly connect to the Internet router, IGMP will be dropped.

Tunneling can be used to carry multicast packets across the Internet, however. You can also get a Mutlicast-VPN from an ISP. Page 2 in the following:

http://www22.verizon.com/wholesale/attachments/solutions/W5032.pdf

Regards.